# "Not Enough iCloud Storage" when trying to upload pictures to iCloud

Tags: iphone, icloud, backup, photos

I have 45 gb left in iCloud storage, however.

Any possible solutions to this?

[image]

Comment: And how much space does what you want to upload occupy?

Comment: @MarcWilson Wouldn't expect Photos to stop uploading due to missing iCloud storage if there are still 45 GB free...

Comment: Have you tried switching iCloud Photos to off and back on and restarting your device?

Comment: @nohillside I have no idea how Apple might implement their service, that's why I asked how much space the data actually occupies.  I think it'd be worse if it uploaded some of it, and then you had to figure out what it hadn't.

Comment: After a couple of days, all the photos have been updated to iCloud. Not sure why it took this long. Thanks for the responses.